# how to loop mp3 sound file without gap in android

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

their are some questions on stackoverflow  about looping sound in android but neither gave me correct answer so i start new thread,
I want to loop a sound without gaps in android. I tried to use the code mediaplayer.setLooping(true) for mp3,ogg and wav file to loop the sound, but there is always a little pause when the first sound is over and the next sound start..my audio length is 2 min. and file size is more than 1 mb so i cant use soundpool for repeating sound.
i didn't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok basically you have to create two objects of media player and then if time of first music is going to b finished then call the other one and your problem is solver

Comment: how do you determine the first is going be finished.

Comment: because over here we are using timer